# Stand alone DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, directoryservices

I'm on a stand alone Windows 10 laptop and NOT running AD LDS or any other active directory services.  I'm running IIS.

I'm trying to deeply understand what this line of code is doing and more importantly, how.

```
DirectoryEntry e3 = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root");
```

Does a windows OS fake in some sort of resolution for this method in absence of active directory?

Comment: Windows doesn't fake anything - there's an LDAP-style provider for the `IIS://` namespace that allows you to query and navigate the IIS metadata (sites, virtual directories etc.) with the `DirectoryEntry` class

Comment: @marc_s  Thanks.  Do you have a link to details? Do you now more about how to access the service or what it is technically called?  Is it only available if IIS is running? How secure do you think that is?  What other things are queryable via this?  Can I find it in the registry somewhere?  What executable/service am I hitting when I query this, Server.exe / workstation.exe, something else?

Comment: See [Using System.DirectoryServices to configure IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791(v=vs.90).aspx) and related MSDN documentation

Comment: @marc_s Not quite all the detail I'd like to find but that link lead me in the right direction.  Any tips on this 0x80005000 error you commented on in other SO questions?  I've read a ton about it.  My uri @"IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/Default Web Site"  (and about a 100 different versions of this uri) and I can't seem to get rid of the error under my login, or running as administrator, or by passing credentials in DirectoryEntry().  All that I read other people are querying LDAP:// and GC:// ... but not IIS://

Comment: @marc_s so I take the executable I'm building on this Win10Pro workstation and drop it on another Win10Pro workstation.  On the other workstation the executable does what I would expect.  Only that now I'm getting "path not found" for MetabasePath.   It explicitly tells me it is a permissions issue on the other workstation.  If I run the executable on the other workstation as administrator it works as I would expect.  The only thing I can think is different is the second workstation is without a firewall.  I disable the firewall on my first workstation and I still get the same 0x80005000

Comment: Sorry, I've never really used the IIS:// provider much ....

Comment: @marc_s thanks for helping as much as you have.  Hopefully the notes  in the question will be useful to others.  All-in-all this thing is working for all I've learned and documented above for the uris IIS://10.0.1.55 , IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc , IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc/1 , and IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc/1/root.  ... I no longer use 'localhost' so I have to use the actual ip address...   But I can't query/ access my site's by using uris IIS://10.0.1.55/mysite , IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc/mysite , IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc/1/mysite , or IIS://10.0.1.55/w3svc/1/root/mysite.  Any tips on how to query specific sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First take care to note if you mean pre/port IIS7.  With and after IIS7 many things changed yet, all to much, they still look alike.  But there are important differences.

2) MAKE SURE you are at least running in administrative mode

> run as administrator

~ or doing something better.

3) Look into .net's `DirectoryServices()/DirectoryEntry()` but also `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager()`.  This is probably where you can do 90% of all you are attempting.

4) There is a windows tool cmdline exe (`windows/syswow64[system32]/inetsvr/appcmd.exe`) that is wonderfully helpful ~ in fact, if it is an option for your needs/environment, you might prefer to create a cmd script for all that you are trying to do.  I suggest first learn this tool, then use it to extract out a lot of the IIS/Site metadata to explore what & where you are trying to get to.  https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools

5) Powershell has a snapin, certainly on server with IIS installed, maybe on workstations.  I don't use a lot of powershell so the most i will say about that is the snapin is called WebAdministration and/or iisConsole.  You may need to/prefer to manually register the snapin each time you run your script OR you might automatically register the snapin by using the IIS powershell management console.

6) For any above option always remember #2 ~ be certain you are at least running in administrative mode.

7) I know you certainly are playing in the land of IIS's metadata database ~ not the registry so much.

**Local workstation:** The exact mechanics when you are local to the IIS instance? I'm not sure.  You might be accessing the metadata directly, you might be getting to the metadata via the IIS service, or you might be accessing the Server.exe Server service, or something else.

**Remote server w/o LDAP:** If you are querying a remote server not in an active directory? same as a workstation.

**Remote server w/ LDAP:** If you are querying a server in an AD you almost certainly are hitting the AD/LDAP service.  Of course, how you are doing so might technically be via a segregate such as server.exe service running on that remote.

-- The end game is appcmd.exe, powershell, or c# Microsoft.Web.Administration, DirectoryServer(), all probably come close to doing the same thing in the background.  But these are your interfaces to access that background so you don't need to think so much about the deeper implementation.

I hope this helps everyone!
Up vote it is you like this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Awesome answer